# How to get different discount rules and discount amount for a particular product?

Tags: product, discount, catalog-price-rules

I need to get different catalog price rules applied for a particular product along with individual discount price splitup.

- Product A - $50 after discount Now $35
- New year sale - $10
- Winter sale - $5.

Answer (score 2):

For one particular product you don't even need catalog price rules, you can set the "special price" directly in the product. Catalog price rules are nothing but automatically applied special prices.

To explain how the discount was calculated I would suggest adding that info to the product description. Magento does not show a discount name next to the special price.